# Select only specific elements in table with css

Tags: css, wordpress

I am stuck with some CSS wordpres styling. I would like to style this paragraph, but how can I select only the first two "li" (featured,featured2)?

```
<div class="categories-wrp" data-type="cliparts">
<ul class="smooth">
<li data-act"item" data-id="{featured}"></li>
<li data-act"item" data-id="{featured2}"></li>
<li data-act"item" data-id="110"></li>
<li data-act"item" data-id="111"></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: li:nth-child(-n+2)

Comment: You can use :first-child and :first-child + li on your ul selector

Comment: `{featured}` is a placeholder for a template engine? or is it visible on the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options: 1. by `first-child` and `nth-child(2)`. 2. by attribute selector `[data-id="{featured}"]`

```css
li {
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.o1 li:first-child,
.o1 li:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: blue;
}


.o2 li[data-id="{featured}"],
.o2 li[data-id="{featured2}"] {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="categories-wrp o1" data-type="cliparts">
  <ul class="smooth">
    <li data-act"item" data-id="{featured}"></li>
    <li data-act"item" data-id="{featured2}"></li>
    <li data-act"item" data-id="110"></li>
    <li data-act"item" data-id="111"></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="categories-wrp o2" data-type="cliparts">
  <ul class="smooth">
    <li data-act"item" data-id="{featured}"></li>
    <li data-act"item" data-id="110"></li>
    <li data-act"item" data-id="{featured2}"></li>
    <li data-act"item" data-id="111"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following solution, using [`nth-child`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/CR-selectors-3-20180130/#nth-child-pseudo):

```css
ul.smooth li:nth-child(1), 
ul.smooth li:nth-child(2) {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="categories-wrp" data-type="cliparts">
  <ul class="smooth">
    <li data-act"item" data-id="{featured}">Test</li>
    <li data-act"item" data-id="{featured2}">Test</li>
    <li data-act"item" data-id="110">Test</li>
    <li data-act"item" data-id="111">Test</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

If you want to format all featured `<li>` elements you can also use the following solution using [attribute selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/CR-selectors-3-20180130/#attribute-selectors):

```css
ul.smooth li[data-id*="featured"] {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="categories-wrp" data-type="cliparts">
  <ul class="smooth">
    <li data-act"item" data-id="{featured}">Test</li>
    <li data-act"item" data-id="{featured2}">Test</li>
    <li data-act"item" data-id="110">Test</li>
    <li data-act"item" data-id="111">Test</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="categories-wrp" data-type="cliparts">
  <ul class="smooth">
    <li data-act"item" data-id="{featured}">Test</li>
    <li data-act"item" data-id="110">Test</li>
    <li data-act"item" data-id="{featured2}">Test</li>
    <li data-act"item" data-id="{featured3}">Test</li>
    <li data-act"item" data-id="111">Test</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Note:** This is only working if `{featured}` and `{featured2}` not replaced by a template engine (like Smarty or Blade).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.smooth ul li:nth-child(-n+2){
    color: red;
}
```

Check out this website, could be useful if this doesn't do the trick:
[:nth child recipes](https://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/)

And [:nth child tester.](https://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/)